# Can Minio decide to delete files for some reason?

Tags: cluster-computing, replication, minio

I have a Minio Replicated system with **4 nodes**.
It worked well for about 1 year. Then, recently, after some curruption and uploading errors, it has been decided to upgrade the Minio version several times during the last two weeks to check if the corruption problem derived from some already fixed issues. Then suddenly **files started to disappear from Minio**, more than 1TB of data has been lost, so it has been decided to downgrade the minio cluster to a single minio instance temporary.

Therefore, i would like to understand the logic of **how distributed minio** communicates to the others nodes to **delete objects**, and if there is a chance that minio could, **by itself**,  delete objects because they are currupted or inconsistent, due to disk damage or a power blackout.

Comment: This is a very interesting question
I think minio has an internal and synchronized database where the status of each file is set
but I'm not sure about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question

I have been following this [question](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/14445) very carefully on the minio forum on Github and I believe it is time to summarize it a bit.

```
The answer to your question is NO!
```

But there have been some bugs in the various versions of minio that have meant that in the case of minio replicated:

- [if you send a request via Http to the various replicas to create the buckets while the minio server is still in the init phase, minio deletes all buckets](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/14445) ([fix pull](https://github.com/minio/minio/pull/14452))
- [If any serverPool returns an error during the creation, Minio deletes the created bucket!](https://github.com/minio/minio/pull/13368)

as already said the two bugs have been fixed, so I recommend any minio user to update to RELEASE.2022-03-08T22-28-51Z or latest.

Comment: See also https://github.com/minio/minio/discussions/14392 for a discussion in what cases MinIO delete objects automatically